# UIPickerView inside UIPopoverController: [UIPickerView setFrame:]: invalid height value pinned

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uipickerview

I face a strange problem about using UIPickerView inside UIPopoverController. I write this task by the following code:

```
    UIPickerView *select = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 216)];
    select.delegate = self;
    select.dataSource = self;

    UIViewController *sortViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    sortViewController.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 216)];

    sortViewController.view = select;
    sortViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 216);

    self.provincePickerPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:sortViewController];
    self.provincePickerPopover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 216);
    self.provincePickerPopover.delegate = self;

    [self.provincePickerPopover presentPopoverFromRect:self.provinceField.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

The problem is when the popover is starting, the following error occurred:

```
[UIPickerView setFrame:]: invalid height value 229.0 pinned to 216.0
```

It is obvious in my code that I never used 229 for height of UIPickerView. How could I fix the problem?

Thanks

Comment: check my answer i have edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the picker view as a subview of the UIViewController's view. That will get rid of the error. So, like this:

```
 ...
 UIViewController *sortViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
 sortViewController.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 216)];

 [sortViewController.view addSubview:select]
 sortViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 216);
...
```